# jQuery events on dynamic elements don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a custom tooltip by attaching hover event handlers to elements with a `title` attribute.

The code works on elements at page load, but when I try to incorporate dynamic elements, the tooltip is not disappearing when my mouse leaves the target element.

**Show Tooltip**

```
Urb.showTooltip = function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var $tooltip = $element.data('tooltip');
    var $tip = $element.attr('title');

    console.log('show');

    if(!$tooltip) {
        // create a tooltip element
        $tooltip = $('<div />');
        $tooltip.addClass('tooltip');
        $tooltip.text($tip);
        Urb.$body.append($tooltip);

        // position the tooltip
        Urb.positionTooltip($tooltip, $element);
        $element.data('tooltip', $tooltip);

        // activate custom tooltip and deactivate browser tooltip
        $tooltip.addClass('active');
        $element.attr('tooltip', $tip);
        $element.removeAttr('title');
    } else {
        // position and activate custom tooltip
        Urb.positionTooltip($tooltip, $element);
        $tooltip.addClass('active');
    }
};
```

**Hide Tooltip**

```
Urb.hideTooltip = function() {
    var $element = $(this);
    var $tooltip = $element.data('tooltip');

    console.log('hide');

    if($tooltip){
        $tooltip.removeClass('active');
    }
};
```

*Note: `Urb` is just a global object I've created as a namespace for my project.*

So, nothing crazy going on there. I originally attached the tooltip logic to jQuery's [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function:

```
$('[title]').hover( Urb.showTooltip, Urb.hideTooltip );
```

That worked just fine, but now, when I try to attach the events to dynamic elements, the `Urb.hideTooltip` is not getting called at all, as it doesn't even log "hide" to my console.

```
Urb.$body.on('mouseover', '[title]', Urb.showTooltip);
Urb.$body.on('mouseleave', '[title]', Urb.hideTooltip);
```

*Note: `Urb.$body` is reference to `$('body')`*

Why doesn't the `hideTooltip` function get called? What am I missing?

Comment: Do you get "show" in you console for dynamic elements? do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes, I do get "show" in the console and the tooltip does everything like normally does, positioning and activating. I don't get any errors. It just doesn't seem to trigger for some reason.

Comment: After appending/adding dynamic content, do you initiate (bind hover events to) those too with: `$('[title]').hover( Urb.showTooltip, Urb.hideTooltip );`?

Comment: There might be a reference error when using `$(this)` inside the function when it is called from the `mouseover` event attached to `body`, 'cause it would be referencing the body, not the item

Comment: No, I'm not initiating those events in any other way. They are just added once on the `window.load` event.

Comment: Then the new element doesn't have an event listener bound to it, so it won't fire the function

Comment: if you do not bind the event to new dynamic elements, howcome you get the `show` message in the console for them?

Comment: @Philip I'm not sure if that is correct. I am using the second parameter in the `on` event specifically for this purpose of auto-attaching the function to dynamic elements. And, as expected, my dynamic elements get `show` in the console and the tooltips show up. They just don't hide on dynamic or non-dynamic elements. That's because `hide` isn't even getting called. Is `mouseleave` the right event? I thought I tried `mouseout` and `mouseenter` to no avail.

Comment: now the scenario has changed, so the `hideTooltip` does not fire even for none-dynamic elements?

Comment: @EhsanT Correct. hide does not fire anymore after changing from `.hover(show, hide)` to `.on('mouseover', show)` and `.on('mouseleave', hide)`. I tried `mouseout` just now, but it didn't work.

Comment: have you tried `mouseout` instead of `mouseleave` just in case?!

Comment: Yes. I also just tried using `$('body')` and `$(document)`...Nothing. Something weird is going on.

Comment: `$tooltip.removeClass('active');` is incorrect, since `$tooltip` is a string, not a jQuery object

Comment: You are using `$tooltip` in two ways: as the data-text and as reference to the newly created object (div). Try using 1 name for each

Comment: @Philip Thanks for pointing that out. I was wondering if that might be a problem. I'll give it a try, though. It's weird that it _does work_ when I do `$('[title]').hover( Urb.showTooltip, Urb.hideTooltip );`.

Comment: I made an example from your code (see answer) and changed it a little :) I'll put some comments in it to explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Use CSS-only `:hover` tooltips using `:after` pseudo-elements with `content: attr( title ) )`.

See: [W3schools](http://w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp)

*Warning*: this is not for all browsers out there, like IE, who gets left behind everytime... ;)

**Solution 2**

I've rewritten your code somewhat, to avoid referencing errors, etc. The only thing missing is the positioning function.

EDIT: Now it doesn't use a single tooltip `<div>`, but sets up tooltip `<div>`'s for each item on first hover, by removing the `title` and after using it to create the tooltip `<div>`.

Have a look:

```js
var Urb = {};

Urb.showTooltip = function() {
    // Get current element
    var $element = $(this);

    // Get tooltip data (if it's there)
    var tooltipText = $element.data('tooltip');

    // Get title for backup
    var tip = $element.attr('title');

    console.log('show');

    // If title is still set, set it to tooltip data and remove title attribute
    if( typeof tip !== undefined && tip !== false) {
        // Remove title attribute
        $element.removeAttr('title');
        // Create new tooltip div
        var $newTip = $('<div />').addClass('tooltip').text( tip );
        // Append it to the element
        $element.append( $newTip );
    }

    $element.find('div.tooltip').addClass('active');
    
};


Urb.hideTooltip = function() {

    console.log('hide');

    // Empty tooltip div and deactivate it
    $(this).find('div.tooltip').removeClass('active');

};



var last_item_nr = 3;

function addItem() {
  var next_nr = ++last_item_nr;
  
  $elm = $('<div></div>');
  
  $elm
    .html('Item ' + next_nr + '<div class="tooltip">Tooltip for item ' + next_nr + '</div>' )
    .hover( Urb.showTooltip, Urb.hideTooltip );
  
  $('#items').append( $elm );
  
  console.log( 'Added item ' + next_nr );
}


$( document ).ready(function() {

  Urb.$body = $('body');

  $('#items > div').hover( Urb.showTooltip, Urb.hideTooltip );

});
```

```css
#items > div {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
}

#items > div > .tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0;
}

#items > div > .tooltip.active {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="addItem();">Add item</button>
<div id="items">
  <div title="Tooltip for item 1">Item 1</div>
  <div title="Tooltip for item 2">Item 2</div>
  <div title="Tooltip for item 3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and effort @Philip. I appreciate it. I was trying to use multiple tooltip elements so that one could fade in while another fades out. I was trying to store the actual `$tooltip` object in my element's `data` so I could reference it later, whereas you are just reusing the same tooltip element. You're also doing what I was originally using (jQuery's `.hover()`), except that you're making another call after adding items. There are lots of ways items can be added to my DOM and I want to make it truly dynamic, so I don't have to keep doing that.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use a element's data for such a reference (I believe). But you can append the tooltip `div` to each element and have it hidden/show up with CSS.

Comment: According to the [jQuery API Documentation for .data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/): "The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks." Maybe I'm misunderstanding that, but regardless, my logic in theory should still at least write "hide" to the console.

Answer (score 1):

OMG, I can't believe I didn't think of this!!!

In my `showTooltip` function, I am removing the `title` attribute!

What an idiot!!

```
$element.removeAttr('title');
```

So, when the tooltip showed, the dynamic element check stopped working. I commented out that line of code and it works.

Now, I just have to figure out how to prevent the browser tooltip from showing.

**Update:**

Turns out I did need to remove the `title` attribute in order to disable browser tooltips. So, I made a few changes to my dynamic selector.

```
 // showTooltip
 $element.attr('data-title', $tip);
 $element.removeAttr('title');

 // window.load
 Urb.$body.on('mouseover', '[title], [data-title]', Urb.showTooltip);
 Urb.$body.on('mouseleave', '[title], [data-title]', Urb.hideTooltip);
```

Comment: I changed my script to check for the title and 'replace' it with a new div tooltip, so you don't need to hide the titles :)

Comment: @Philip Thanks again for your time. I up-voted your answer. Turns out my code and logic were pretty much spot on with what I needed. I was just overlooking that my `title` attribute was being removed, thus eliminating it from the dynamic selector. I'm thankful that you were online at the same time as me to give me an opportunity to "think out loud".

Comment: :) you're welcome! Btw: why not use CSS-only hover tooltips using `:after` pseudo-elements with `content: attr( title )` )? See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_content.asp

Comment: Might save a lot of coding and computing time? ;)

Comment: LOL, why did I not think of doing it that way? I've done it before. Sheesh. Brain is fried from working too much. Currently, I'm using the `:after` pseudo-class on my tooltip element in order to get a little "arrow" pointing at the hovered element, but that is just a superfluous design requirement. I will seriously consider revising that now. Cheers.

Comment: @Philip, if you want to add that recommendation to your answer, I'll mark it as accepted because that is a much more ideal solution and future visitors should consider that first. Although, I'm not sure about the manual positioning I'm doing to ensure tooltips stay within the viewport.

Comment: Haha, we've all been there :) You can still use `:before` then